# How do I 'efficiently' replace a vector of strings with another (pairwise) in a large text corpus

Tags: r, text-mining, gsub, large-data

I have a large corpus of text in a vector of strings (app. 700.000 strings). I'm trying to replace specific words/phrases within the corpus. That is, I have a vector of app 40.000 phrases and a corresponding vector of replacements.

I'm looking for an efficient way of solving the problem

I can do it in a for loop, looping through each pattern + replacement. But it scales badly (3 days or so !)

I'v also tried qdap::mgsub(), but it seems to scale badly as well

```r
txt <- c("this is a random sentence containing bca sk", 
"another senctence with bc a but also with zqx tt",
"this sentence contains non of the patterns", 
"this sentence contains only bc a")

patterns <- c("abc sk", "bc a", "zqx tt")

replacements <- c("@a-specfic-tag-@abc sk", 
"@a-specfic-tag-@bc a", 
"@a-specfic-tag-@zqx tt")

#either
txt2 <- qdap::mgsub(patterns, replacements, txt)
#or
for(i in 1:length(patterns)){
    txt  <- gsub(patterns[i], replacements[i], txt)
}
```

Both solutions scale badly for my data with app 40.000 patterns/replacements and 700.000 txt strings

I figure there must be a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can tokenize the texts first, then vectorized replacement is much faster.  It's also faster if a) you can use a multi-threaded solution and b) you use fixed instead of regular expression matching.

Here's how to do all that in the **quanteda** package.  The last line pastes the tokens back into a single "document" as a character vector, if that is what you want.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
## 
## Attaching package: 'quanteda'
## The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
## 
##     View
quanteda_options(threads = 4)

txt <- c(
  "this is a random sentence containing bca sk",
  "another sentence with bc a but also with zqx tt",
  "this sentence contains none of the patterns",
  "this sentence contains only bc a"
)
patterns <- c("abc sk", "bc a", "zqx tt")
replacements <- c(
  "@a-specfic-tag-@abc sk",
  "@a-specfic-tag-@bc a",
  "@a-specfic-tag-@zqx tt"
)
```

This will tokenize the texts and then use fast replacement of the hashed types, using a fixed pattern match (but you could have used `valuetype = "regex"` for regular expression matching).  By wrapping `patterns` inside the `phrases()` function, you are telling `tokens_replace()` to look for token sequences rather than individual matches, so this solves the multi-word issue.

```r
toks <- tokens(txt) %>%
  tokens_replace(phrase(patterns), replacements, valuetype = "fixed")
toks
## tokens from 4 documents.
## text1 :
## [1] "this"       "is"         "a"          "random"     "sentence"  
## [6] "containing" "bca"        "sk"        
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "another"                "sentence"              
## [3] "with"                   "@a-specfic-tag-@bc a"  
## [5] "but"                    "also"                  
## [7] "with"                   "@a-specfic-tag-@zqx tt"
## 
## text3 :
## [1] "this"     "sentence" "contains" "none"     "of"       "the"     
## [7] "patterns"
## 
## text4 :
## [1] "this"                 "sentence"             "contains"            
## [4] "only"                 "@a-specfic-tag-@bc a"
```

Finally if you really want to put this back into character format, then convert to a list of character types and then paste them together.

```r
sapply(as.list(toks), paste, collapse = " ")
##                                                                             text1 
##                                     "this is a random sentence containing bca sk" 
##                                                                             text2 
## "another sentence with @a-specfic-tag-@bc a but also with @a-specfic-tag-@zqx tt" 
##                                                                             text3 
##                                     "this sentence contains none of the patterns" 
##                                                                             text4 
##                                "this sentence contains only @a-specfic-tag-@bc a"
```

You'll have to test this on your large corpus, but 700k strings does not sound like too large a task.  Please try this and report how it did!

Comment: Hi sorry for the late answer. I had an urgent task to complete.

I get the following error `Error in qatd_cpp_tokens_replace(x, type, ids_pat, ids_repl) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=NULL; target=double].`

Comment: For errors, please file at https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues.

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector of all words in each phrase

```
txt1 = strsplit(txt, " ")
words = unlist(txt1)
```

Use `match()` to find the index of words to replace, and replace them

```
idx <- match(words, patterns)
words[!is.na(idx)] = replacements[idx[!is.na(idx)]]
```

Re-form the phrases and paste together

```
phrases = relist(words, txt1)
updt = sapply(phrases, paste, collapse = " ")
```

I guess this won't work if patterns can have more than one word...

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, patterns do often have more words.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map between the old and new values

```
map <- setNames(replacements, patterns)
```

Create a pattern that contains all patterns in a single regular expression

```
pattern = paste0("(", paste0(patterns, collapse="|"), ")")
```

Find all matches, and extract them

```
ridx <- gregexpr(pattern, txt)
m <- regmatches(txt, ridx)
```

Unlist, map, and relist the matches to their replacement values, and update the original vector

```
regmatches(txt, ridx) <- relist(map[unlist(m)], m)
```

Comment: Tanks... I get an error, though, in

```r
ridx <- gregexpr(pattern, txt)
```

the error message is

```r
Error in gregexpr(pattern, txt) : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634
```

Comment: I'd guess that the problem is too large; you could try to tackle a subset of patterns to see how feasible the approach is; if it 'works' using say 1000 patterns and is faster than your current iteration approach, then apply the solution in 'chunks' of 1000 patterns